# can I update the claims value in net 6 without using userManager?

Tags: cookies, .net-6.0, claims

I'm stuck at when I try to update my user claims on profile update but get not any single solution working for net 6. can anyone guide me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you can use cookies  instead  if you want to  update  profile. or you can use the owin as well.